# reading SchedLgU.Txt file using java prog getting output with junvalue with boxes

Tags: java

I have written following code to read system generated file for scheduled task i.e. SchedLgU.Txt

```
File f = new File("C:\\WINDOWS\\Tasks\\SchedLgU.Txt");
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(f);
// Get the object of DataInputStream
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line="";
do{
    line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}  while(br.readLine()!=null);
```

I am getting some junk value with characters with boxes.

Is there any different format I have to define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're using `InputStreamReader` without specifying a character encoding - so it will always use the platform default encoding. It looks like this file is in UTF-16 (at least on my box). Just pass that encoding to the `InputStreamReader` constructor to read the file properly.

Trying it with your test program, that seems to work. Note that there's no point using a `DataInputStream` if you're just going to wrap it in an `InputStreamReader` - just pass the `FileInputStream` directly to the `InputStreamReader` constructor:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream, "UTF-16"));
```